# Symmetric Matrix Confused

Tags: matrices

Consider a matrix, $$\begin{matrix}2 & 8\\-8 & 2\end{matrix}$$ is this a symmetrical matrix or skew symmetrical matrix?  Its transpose does not equal to itself so it can't be symmetrical. Its diagonal does not equal to zero so it can't be skew symmetrical. I am confused.

Comment: It is neither symmetrical, nor skew symmetrical as you say. What is your objection? You have it already.

Comment: Are you perhaps confused because you think that a general matrix is either symmetric or skew symmetric? It can be neither.

Comment: It's a Toeplitz matrix.

Answer (score 2):

The correct conclusion is that it is neither symmetric nor skew-symmetric, for exactly the reasons you have provided.